# Clojure & ActiveMQ & Storm: consume from queue using clojure

Tags: clojure, activemq-classic, apache-storm

I would like to connect and consume from a queue using Clojure. I do not know which is the best clojure API (Storm-JMS??) for that task.

Does somebody knows which API is the best? 
Maybe you have an example of how the consuming is done in Clojure?

My final goal is to write a storm spout using the clojure macro *defspout* and consume tuples from a queue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Regards, Horace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To supplement Nicolas Modrzyk: [Langohr](https://github.com/michaelklishin/langohr) is a very nice Clojure API for [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), which integrates well with Storm.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started with storm, there is a [word count example](https://github.com/denno-clojure/mascarpone/blob/master/chapter05_storm/src/clj/storm/starter/clj/word_count_0.clj) project ready for you on github:

https://github.com/denno-clojure/mascarpone/tree/master/chapter05_storm

Dependencies are all in the project.clj file and runs out of the box.

Although, just to make sure, Storm is doing the processing and can [integrate with external queueing systems](http://storm-project.net/about/integrates.html).
If you simply need to use a queueing system, look at some of the following samples:

- [Clojure with ActiveMQ](https://github.com/denno-clojure/mascarpone/blob/master/chapter05/src/clamq.clj)
- [Redis publisher](https://github.com/denno-clojure/mascarpone/blob/master/chapter05/src/redis_pub.clj) and [Redis subscriber](https://github.com/denno-clojure/mascarpone/blob/master/chapter05/src/redis_sub.clj)